# Open Apple Maps for navigation with destination name set

Tags: ios, apple-maps

I am fetching location data (like the coordinates used below) from Google's Places API.

When linking to Apple Maps for navigation from my app, I am currently using:

`https://maps.apple.com/?daddr=[latitude],[longitude]`

When Maps opens, it presents the coordinates for a short amount of time before resolving to an address. **What I want is for the name of the destination to appear instead of coordinates or an address.** Since I am using React Native, I would *prefer* a javascript-only solution (knowing that this essentially restricts a solution to this question to a url).

I have tried combinations of other parameters listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this function, you only need to pass the coordinates and place name, this works, I use this in several projects

```
static func openMapsAppWithLocation(coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D,placeName:String)
{
    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = placeName
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So I'm guessing there's no way to do this with the url only. I ask because I am using react native and would prefer a javascript-only solution.

Comment: @Palisand I think must be a way using the url, but in your question you are missing the specification that you need the solution in javascript and this is an important part of your question.

Comment: Good point, I'll update it. Your solution is still viable with react native, since it supports native modules.

Comment: @Palisand then you have this solved, if someone else put an answer as url,  should be nicer for your, but if don't you can use this anyway, best regards