# Apple Map set destination using iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-maps

I am working on iOS App which deals with location and address. I want to set destination in Navigation app present in Users iPhone device.
My iOS App will send GPS co-ordinate or address to Apple Maps, and this location should be set as destination in Apple Map application.

I have few queries:

Is there any API provided by apple to set destination in Apple Maps app?

Is it possible to know if Navigation is already active and get destination?

Can we add way-points if Destination is already set?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514883/open-apple-maps-for-navigation-with-destination-name-set/45515985#45515985

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post. You might want to take a look at our help center page on [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for info. But, This queries are on the same topic and closely related.

Answer (score 1):

At first create an annotation of the destination and then use this code:

```
let place: MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate:annotation.coordinate)
let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: place)
destination.name = "Your destination name"
let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 1000
let regionSpan = 
MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, regionDistance, regionDistance)
let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:  NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span), MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving] as [String : Any]
//Open the map App
MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [destination], launchOptions: options)
```

Comment: Thank you for info. Is it also possible to know if destination is already set and add waypoints?